# Issue with MS AJAX reorder list. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

am using a reorder list in my UI. My reorder list is and SQLDataSource are shown below. I get an error message

"Reorder failed, see details below.\r\n\r\nFailed to reorder."

Seems trivial but not able to find the issue. Can you please help me with this issue ?

SOURCE CODE

                                
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                               ' />

```
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TBL_BATCH_STAGE WHERE RQUST_KEY=@RequestId ORDER BY [ORDER_NO] ASC" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TBL_BATCH_STAGE] SET [ORDER]=@Order WHERE [BATCH_STG_KEY] = @original_ID"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="RequestId" SessionField="RequestId" />
    </SelectParameters>
       <UpdateParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="Order" Type="Int32" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
       </UpdateParameters>
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue.My SQL parameters did not match my ReorderList variable names.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"  OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TBL_BATCH_STAGE WHERE RQUST_KEY=@RequestId ORDER BY [ORDER_NO] ASC" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TBL_BATCH_STAGE] SET [ORDER_NO]=@ORDER_NO WHERE [BATCH_STG_KEY] = @original_BATCH_STG_KEY" >
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:SessionParameter Name="RequestId" SessionField="RequestId" />
      </SelectParameters>
      <UpdateParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="ORDER_NO" Type="Int32" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="original_BATCH_STG_KEY" Type="Int32" />
      </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>  

    <asp:ReorderList ID="ReorderList1" runat="server" AllowReorder="true" DataKeyField="BATCH_STG_KEY" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" SortOrderField="ORDER_NO">
    <ItemTemplate>
          <table style="border:solid 1px #cccccc;">
             <tr>
               <td style="vertical-align:top;list-style:none;font-size:13px;padding:0 0 0 0;">
                <asp:Label ID="ItemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BATCH_STG_TEXT")%>' />
               </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ReorderList>
```